# DataList does not bind image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Datalist and bind some information on it, but my Datalist is not showing my image.

Here is My Aspx Code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="datalistnewsrelease" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke"
                    RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" Width="100%" OnItemCommand="datalistnews_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="newsbox m5">
            <p class="black">
                <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" class="b red" Text='<%#Eval("NewsReleaseDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblmonth" runat="server" class="b red" Text='<%#Eval("NesReleaseMonth") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblyear" runat="server" class="b red" Text='<%#Eval("NewsReleaseYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br>
                <asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" class="b blue" Text='<%#Eval("NewsReleaseTittle") %>'></asp:Label>
                <a href="<%#Eval("NewsReleaseImage")%>" rel="gallery">
                    <img src="<%#Eval("NewsReleaseImage")%>" width="88" height="62" class="fr ml8" alt="">
                </a>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="NewsRelease" runat="server" Style="float: right;" img src="images/read.png"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("NewReleaseId")%>' CommandName="View" />
            </p>
            <div class="cb pb5">
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>`
```

My code is similar to a Gridview I am binding the DataList to, but only that the image is not showing up.

Comment: Have you check your image path "src"?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the value coming to "NewsReleaseImage" .

Is it plain image file name or relative path ? If it's plain file name then append relative your paths in ItemBound, if its fixed then you can append directly like below

> src="/Images/<%#Eval("NewsReleaseImage")%>"

Comment: no it is not working actully i am binding image from sql  data table

Comment: What's the value you getting from Sql table. Is it path or a file name ?? As Carlos suggest , can you check generated HTML ( View Page Source ) and share the src attribute value.

Comment: I am getting path value not file name

Comment: i saw you full my aspx code and my aspx.cs code is here

Comment: DataTable Dtnewsrelease = lo.Retrivenewsletter();
            if (Dtnewsrelease.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                datalistnewsrelease.DataSource = Dtnewsrelease;
                datalistnewsrelease.DataBind();
                datalistnewsrelease.Visible = true;
                Panelrelease.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No News Find Please Add News to View')", true);
                Panelrelease.Visible = false;
            }

Comment: giving a single line replies doesn't help in Forums. Read this article 

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-display-images-in-datalist-control-using-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-1037.aspx

Comment: NOW IT IS WORKING THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to view the generated HTML and see the generated `src` attribute.